# Erased number?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, average

A set of consecutive positive integers starting with 1 is written on the board. A student came along and erased one number. Average of remaining numbers is 61 15/20 . What was the number erased

Comment: '15/20' isn't in simplest form; usually that would be written '3/4'.  Normally I would think that was supposed to indicate that there were 20 numbers left being averaged, but that doesn't seem to apply here...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki:  I think it is a reasonable red herring for a problem like this.  It makes one think the solution must involve a multiple of $20$ (at least it did me).  Much better if there were an answer.

Comment: Note that the answer that currently has most upvotes contains an error, as pointed out by Ross; if the error is corrected, the result is the same as in Ross' answer, namely that there is no solution.

Comment: See [this very similar question](http://gmatclub.com/forum/a-set-of-consecutive-positive-integers-beginning-with-1-is-72724.html). The wording is very similar and a different average is used, and there is a solution.

Comment: @PeterPhipps:  But this one has an added twist.  The method of the link doesn't work here, as N. S. and I prove.

Comment: I think it is unfair to post a problem like this without there being a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n$ be the last number written. Lets say that $m$ is the erased number.

Then the sum of the numbers on the board is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-m$. Their average then is

$$\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-m}{n-1}=61 \frac{15}{20}$$

Multiplying by 2 you get

$$\frac{n(n+1)-2m}{n-1}=122\frac{3}{2}$$

$$\frac{n^2+n-2}{n-1}+\frac{2}{n-1}-\frac{2m}{n-1}=123\frac{1}{2}$$

$$n+2+\frac{2-2m}{n-1}=123 \frac{1}{2}.\tag{$*$}$$

Now, since $1 \leq m \leq n$ we have
$$-2 \leq \frac{2-2m}{n-1} \leq 0 \,.$$

Using the fact that $n+2$ is an integer and $-2 \leq \frac{2-2m}{n-1} \leq 0 \,,$ in $(*)$, you see immediately that there are only two possibilities:

**Case 1:**

$n+2=124$ and $\frac{2-2m}{n-1}=-\frac{1}{2}$

**Case 2:**

$n+2=125$ and $\frac{2-2m}{n-1}=-\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Instead of considering case $1$ and case $2$, we could also make use of the fact that $n = 4k+1$ since $n(n+1)/2 - m = 61 \dfrac34 (n-1)$

Comment: But $61 \frac {15}{20} \times 2 = 122 \frac 32$

Comment: The logic of the solution goes through after the correction.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The average is $61 \frac 34$, and erasing one number can only move it by $\frac 12^+$, so the maximum had to be $122$ or $123$  But the denominator of the average is $4$, so the number of entries must be a multiple of $4$.  This is a contradiction and there is no solution.

**Added:**  There are $124$.  The average starts out $62 \frac 12$, then the $3$ of $103$ was erased, changing it to $10.$  This reduces the sum by $93$ and the average by $\frac 34.$  Some will think this unfair, some will think it clever.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore the the condition *"starting with"* the maxima program

```
for n:60 thru 130 do 
  for m:1 thru n-1 do 
    block([k], 
    k:(2*n^2-2*m^2-245*n+249*m)/4,
    if (integerp(k) and (m<=k) and (k<=n)) then
      print([m,k,n]));
```

will generate all solutions. So even if you interprete the condition *"starting with"*  as *"the first digit of the first number is 1"* (I thought this is this kind of joke) you will have more than one solution.

[start,removed,end]

```
[60,63,64]
[58,64,66]
[56,65,68]
[54,66,70]
[52,67,72]
[50,68,74]
[48,69,76]
[46,70,78]
[44,71,80]
[42,72,82]
[40,73,84]
[38,74,86]
[36,75,88]
[34,76,90]
[32,77,92]
[30,78,94]
[28,79,96]
[26,80,98]
[24,81,100]
[22,82,102]
[20,83,104]
[18,84,106]
[16,85,108]
[14,86,110]
[12,87,112]
[10,88,114]
[8,89,116]
[6,90,118]
[4,91,120]
[2,92,122]
```